# A dependent dll was not found

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

My app does not run on "Release x86" when running the app it crashes immediately after the splash screen. Output shows the following exception:

*The program '[8204] dfz.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent DLL was not found'.*

It also tells me the module is build without symbols, however in build settings I have set debug info to Full.

The first time I build the app for the Windows Store it built correctly and I also published that version to the store. When I did a manual rebuild to check if ads where inserted correctly it would not run.

However, I can run the app on ARM and X64 with no problems on release. Only x86 with .Net native toolchain will throw the missing dependant DLL.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Created a new project, Added all my files and Nuget packages, No dice
2. Removed and updated all my existing references.
3. Tried to debug the release version so i can find out what DLL is missing from the package. However it keeps telling me there are no symbol files.

I am looking for any suggestions I can try because I am really at a loss here of why it will not run on x86.

**Edit:**
A blank UWP project also returns the DLL error when i run it. It looks like i have a broken development environment.

**Edit2:**
Just did a remote debugging session to another laptop and the app worked with no problems. So the problem is an environment related issue.

Comment: Try using this if you can:  http://www.dependencywalker.com/ ; or just use the older library

Comment: I don't think this tool works correctly for UWP apps as the x64 .exe does not display any dependencies and the x86 version shows hundreds of missing system dll's

Comment: thanks for the update; good to know

Comment: what .NET version you using?

Comment: 4.6, but i just discovered it is not just my project. If i open a blank new UWP project and run it with x86 and release it also throws the a dependent DLL was missing error. Looks like i just have a corrupt environment

Comment: Are you trying to run it from a TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt drive?

Answer (score 1):

Could one of the projects in your dependencies be configured specifically for x64?

Another thing to check is that one of your projects is not set to build for that configuration (I vaguely remember some problem I had years ago that sounds kind like your situation ... although not for windows store apps ... and it turned out one of my projects wasn't set to compile for the configuration I was selecting ).

Comment: Yes all projects are set to build to x86