# UWP App Won't Start in Release, "A dependent DLL was not found." Works in Debug, No Additional Info

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio, so it may be very possible I'm missing something obvious, however I'm at a loss, so here goes.

I'm making a UWP app using Visual Studio 2019, everything works fine in debug mode, and I can build it for release, but when I try to start it in release mode I get

```
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. 
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.27328.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mrt100_app.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Tetris.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. 
The thread 0x35ec has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x15b0 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[13780] Tetris.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

in the debug output.

I've tried searching online, and the only thing I really could find is: [A dependent dll was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842787/a-dependent-dll-was-not-found), however there is no solution given. I *can* build and run an empty solution though, and I've also tried repairing Visual Studio.

I also found https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe9b56b6-65f3-404c-917c-173024a50835/getting-a-dependent-dll-was-not-found-how-do-i-find-out-which-dll?forum=winappswithnativecode, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to apply gflags to a UWP app. And, considering it works in debug, I'm not even sure a dll is missing.

I've installed *all* of the .net frameworks through the Visual Studio Installer, and checked my NuGet packages (MathNet.Numerics and Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform): I meet all of their requirements.

It's also happening for both x86 and x64.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) in background while trying to launch the Release version and filter for DLL Load events for the app and look which ones can't be loaded.

Comment: @magicandre1981, I did that and saw that Math.Net was trying to load a bunch of .dlls for MKL. I tried removing Math.Net entirely, and it runs now. I know where to focus my attention now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and for introducing me to the process monitor.

Comment: This is pretty much supposed to happen when testing the .NETNative build, tells you that it isn't going to pass certification.  Math.NET is tricky because of its dependency on native code, be sure to run WACK.  [More here](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/579).